# Can the use of C++11's 'auto' deteriorate performance or even break the code?

Tags: c++, c++11, lazy-evaluation, auto

This question is the opposite of an existing question "[Can the use of C++11's 'auto' improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510183/can-the-use-of-c11s-auto-improve-performance)"

[One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32758566/6394138) to that question indicated that usage of `auto` can have not only positive but also negative effects.

I believe we need a separate question, with answers focusing on that side of `auto`.

Comment: Mindlessly doing a search and replace of all variable declarators with `auto` will almost certainly break your code. Think about `cv` and ref qualifiers. A plain `auto` isn't *usually* the same as a `cv` or ref qualified `auto`. .... Think about conversions that `auto` wouldn't do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `auto` there is no conversion at the variable declaration+initialization line. But if such conversion must happen anyway, it better happen once during initialization than multiple times later.

```
struct X {
    ...
};

struct Y {
    operator X() const;
    ...
};

Y foo(); // maybe, originally its return type was X but later was changed to Y
void bar(const X& );

const auto x = foo();           // <-- conversion not happening here
                                //
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) //
    bar(x);                     // <-- silently rages here
```

Such a deferred conversion may break the code when `auto` is combined with lazy evaluation (real world [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099246/wrong-results-using-auto-with-eigen), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38354521/why-does-gcc-optimization-not-work-with-valarrays)):

```
class Matrix { ... };

class MatrixExpression {
    ...
    operator Matrix() const;
};

MatrixExpression operator+(const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b);
std::ostream& operator(std::ostream& out, const Matrix& m);

Matrix a = ...;
Matrix b = ...;
auto c = a + b; // evaluation of the matrix addition doesn't happen here
a[0][0] += 1;
std::cout << c; // matrix addition is evaluated here, using the new state of 'a'
```

Comment: It also affects overload resolution and template instantiation. `long x = 1; cout << sizeof(x);` changes behavior if `long` becomes `auto`. And as a special case `int* p = 0:` changes meaning significantly if you rewrite it as `auto p = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

Your question title specifies 'performance'.

`auto` is a compile time construct that allows itself to be substituted with a deduced type. Its use doesn't result in different machine instructions, than if you have hand-written the typename it deduced.

The problem is that, in managing performance, type specification and casting is often crucial, and `auto` can hide that leading programmers to say something different than they intended:

```
std::vector<std::array<BigStruct, 10000>>& f();
auto va = f();  // copy
for (auto v: va) {  // copies
    // ...
}
```

if the programmer had written:

```
std::vector<std::array<BigStruct, 10000>> va = f();
```

or

```
for (std::array<BigStruct, 10000> v : va)
```

they would have recognized they were specifying by-value. But `std::array<BigStruct, 10000>` is what `auto` deduces here and in these cases that translates to by-value.

People drop their guard and forget that `auto` deduces the *type*, it doesn't include the ref qualification.

```
auto& va = f();  // reference
for (auto& v : va) {  // references
```

There was a performance affect here, but it wasn't caused by `auto` it was a side-effect of (accidentally) explicitly specifying a copy.

`auto` doesn't mean `the same as this` it means `an instance of this`.

```
auto va = f();   // an instance-of what f returns, thus a copy.
auto& va = f();  // a reference to an instance-of, thus by reference.
```

Answer (score 0):

Blind search-and-replace of all type declarations by **auto** can be a head-ache, whenever braced initialization is used:

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point (int x1, int y1) { x = x1; y = y1; }
private:
    int x, y;
};      

int main() 
{
    Point p{5, 6};
    auto q{5, 6}; // Error. Uniform initialization is not REALLY uniform
}
```

The first declaration of variable **p** is correctly deduced as a call to the constructor accepting two integers. But the **auto** variable **q** searches for a constructor requiring **std::initializer_list`<int`>** and hence fails to compile.